# 4 bit to 4 bit subtractor logic gates problem

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to create a 4 bit by 4 bit subtractor here but I get wrong output. In the picture it shows that 0000-1111=10001 which should be 0000-1111=11111. Please help me.
By the way the rightmost IC is a half subtractor and the remaining three are full subtractor.

[image: Click here for the Diagram of the project]

Comment: Why do you think the answer is wrong? In 2's-complement notation, (0)0000 is 0, (0)1111 is +15 and 10001 is -15. Sounds like the right answer to me. 11111 is -1, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm just a student. So, the answer is in 2's-complement sir?

Comment: Yes. What were you expecting?

Comment: I'm not expecting it to be that way. Another question sir. So everytime my subtrahend is greater than my minuend, my answer is in 2's complement?
For example using my project:
A) 1010-1110=11100 <--- this is in 2's complement?
B) 0110-1000=11110 <--- this is in 2's complement?
C) 0000-1000=11000 <--- thus is in 2's complement?

Comment: ALL your numbers are 2's-complement. That's why I showed the implicit sign bit (0) in your original numbers.

Comment: But my circuit works normally when my subtrahend is lower than my minuend.
For example: A) 0110-0001=(0)0101 which is correct and not in 2's complement.

Comment: It IS 2's complement. That's how 2's complement represents positive numbers.

Comment: So what can i do on my circuit sir so all its ouput will be into a normal binary digits not in 2's complement.

Comment: @Rane How will you represent a negative number, in 'normal binary'?

Comment: How do you want to represent negative numbers? If you were expecting a result of (1)1111, that would be called "sign-magnitude" notation. Conversion between 2's-complement and sign-magnitude is straightforward.

Comment: Oh yes, I want my output to be in "sign-magnitude" form.

Comment: OK, then since you're using a 2's-complement subtractor circuit, you're going to have to convert your input numbers from sign-magnitude to 2's-complement and then convert the result back to sign-magnitude. Perhaps now you see why most people just use 2's-complement to begin with.

Comment: Thanks sir for the input. I'll try to edit it now.

Comment: Sirs one last question. When I will defend my project, how will i explain that if the number is negative it is in 2's complement?
I know that computers use 2's complement for signed numbers but what is the process of the project that it makes it 2's complement?